# C# WinForms: Activating a thread when the program activates

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading

All I want to do is to make a thread that activates when the program starts. Is it possible? I tried to to use an event, but I failed at finding the right one (if there is one in the form's properties).

If there is no such event, is there an alternate way to do it?

Comment: do you want start a thread when your program starts ? don't you?

Comment: I found the event! It's "Load".

At first the thread's work was like this:

for (; is_delay_on; )

            {
                Thread.Sleep(500);
                is_delay_on = false;
            }
This way the thread finishes when it starts and this fooled me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using the `Shown` or `Load` events?

Answer (score 2):

If you want the thread to activate when the program starts, just put your thread startup code in your `Main` method (usually in Program.cs).